# Log4J: can I enable/disable logging from a class at runtime?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Sometimes logging needs to be enabled/disabled at runtime only during a specific phase of the execution of a code (e.g. for debugging purposes).
Now, I use Java and Log4J to debug. This is my `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /Users/Admin/Documents/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout, file

#Logging for class Solution in package org.solver will be disabled
log4j.category.org.solver.Solution = OFF, stdout, file

# Define the file Console appender
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Define the file file appender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

As you may see, I log both on a file and on the console output.

Now, suppose that I have a class `X` from package `foo`. How can I enable and disable the logging at runtime? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16380860/1983997) I found a possible answer, but an example would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/28/how-to-reload-log4j-levels-on-runtime/
On the other hand, log4j 2 already has this [funtionality](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticReconfiguration)

Comment: @Pablo Interesting, I'm going to study this code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like :

```
LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

You can also get the exact logger passing class into the get.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks. Clearly, I have to do something like: `Logger.getLogger(foo.X.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);`