# log4j turn of a logger programmatically

Tags: java, log4j

I have a `log4j.properties` file with this content, and it works as expected (I don't get any log from this class):

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.pdfbox = OFF
```

However, I need to achieve the same behaviour programmatically, because I don't have access to the `log4j.properties` file. I've tried as follows:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;
LogManager.getLogger("org.apache.pdfbox").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

But it does not work. I still get log from this class.

How to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4J: can I enable/disable logging from a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322573/log4j-can-i-enable-disable-logging-from-a-class-at-runtime)

Comment: the answer in that post is already mentioned in my question, and it does not work, as explained.